# Using a convolution neural network with a non-image input

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I want to use a convolutional neural network, but I have a 2D array for the input, not an image. I am trying to evaluate a board game state where shapes are important.

The board is 5x5 and the values can be between -1 and 1, stored as a list of lists ex:

```
[[-1,1.0,-1,1,-1],[0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[-1,0.6,-1,-1,1]]
```

the first layer of the model is

```
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), input_shape=(5,5,1))
```

I convert the board to a numpy array

```
np.array([[-1,1.0,-1,1,-1],[0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[-1,0.6,-1,-1,1]])
```

I gather the boards into a list.
Then I convert the list into an array of arrays to fit

```
model.fit(np.array(x_train_l), y_train, epochs=10)
```

I get the following error:

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, 5, 5]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reshape your numpy array to have shape (5,5,1). Currently it is with shape (5,5).

```
 np.array([[-1,1.0,-1,1,-1],[0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[-1,0.6,-1,-1,1]]).reshape(5,5,1)
```

Comment: You can use `data[:, :, np.newaxis]` to achieve the same thing for an existing array `data`.

Comment: both reshape(5,5,1) and data[:, :, np.newaxis] seem to do the trick!

Comment: click that you accept this answer ... so it is 'finished'